# How do I detect my display's resolution in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    ResWidth = Screen.Width \ Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
    ResHeight = Screen.Height \ Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
    ScreenRes = ResWidth & "x" & ResHeight
    MsgBox (ScreenRes)
End Sub
```

And several other similar codes I've googled for.  The problem is, I always get a message box saying that my resolution is 1200x1200, although my actual resolution is 1920x1200.  Why am I getting bad results?

Comment: Add the screen.width, screen.height, twipsperpixelx, and twipsperpixely values to your message box, what do you get?

Comment: Works prefectly on my system! Curious problem....

Comment: I think this should work, it looks fine. Is there anything unusual about the system?

Comment: What about multiple monitors?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why that doesn't work, but you could tap into the Windows API.

```
Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
```

And then when you need the screen width and height, define these constants:

```
Private Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0
Private Const SM_CYSCREEN = 1
```

Then you can use `GetSystemMetrics` wherever you need it.  If it makes more sense to add the declaration and constants to a Module (.BAS), then just make the declaration and constants public.

```
Dim width as Long, height as Long
width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)
```

[GetSystemMetrics on Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/77061)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is a problem with Screen object in VB6. As per KB253940 [PRB: Incorrect Screen Object Width/Height After the Desktop Is Resized](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253940):

> Inside the Visual Basic IDE, the Screen object reports an incorrect value for the desktop width after the screen resolution is changed. When the application is executing outside the IDE, the Width and Height properties of the Screen object return incorrect values if the resolution is changed from the Display Properties icon in the System Tray.

KB suggests to use [GetDeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877.aspx) API function to work around the problem:

```
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" _
        (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Const HORZRES = 8
Private Const VERTRES = 10

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ResWidth = GetDeviceCaps(Form1.hdc, HORZRES)
    ResHeight = GetDeviceCaps(Form1.hdc, VERTRES)
    ScreenRes = ResWidth & "x" & ResHeight
    MsgBox (ScreenRes)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with any Windows Mobile, the way is a bit different. You need to use the following formula:

```
Width = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * 0.32)
```

In the previous example is assigned the 32% of the screen width to `width` variable.

Comment: 35% or 32% ...?

Comment: Corrected, Thanks!! =)

Comment: Why 32% though? Where does such arbitrary number come from?